# Setting same background color to a button and an image button?

Tags: android, android-layout, background

I've got a `Button` object and an `Imagebutton` object. And all I want to do is to assign the same background color to both of them.

But the background color of the image button seems always to be brighter than the color of the "ordinary" button?! A lil bit brighter on the emulator and way brighter on my S3 Mini.
Why?

```
private final int BUTTON_BACKGROUND_COLOR_CODE = Color.LTGRAY;

 ...

RelativeLayout TopLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.topLayout);
TopLayout.removeAllViews();
TopLayout.setPadding(m_TableRowLeftPadding_px, 8, m_TableRowRightPadding_px, 4);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(m_DefaultButtonWidth_px,
    m_CurrentButtonHeight_px);
bParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
bParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

Button itemAddButton = new Button(this);
itemAddButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(BUTTON_BACKGROUND_COLOR_CODE,
    PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

itemAddButton.setLayoutParams(bParams);
itemAddButton.setText(m_Resources.getString(R.string.AddItemButtonString));
itemAddButton.setId(ADD_ITEM_BUTTON_ID);
itemAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
   ...
});

TopLayout.addView(itemAddButton);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ibParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(MIN_IMG_BUTTON_WIDTH,
    m_CurrentButtonHeight_px);
ibParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, itemAddButton.getId());

ImageButton speechButton = new ImageButton(this);

speechButton.setLayoutParams(ibParams);
// speechButton.setImageDrawable(m_Resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.micro2));

speechButton.setContentDescription(m_Resources.getString(R.string.AddSpeechItemString));
speechButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(BUTTON_BACKGROUND_COLOR_CODE,
    PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

speechButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
  ...
});


TopLayout.addView(speechButton);
```

Comment: why dont you use two `Buttons` or two `ImageButtons` instead of one `Button` and `ImageButton`??

Comment: "A lil bit brighter on the emulator and way brighter on my S3 Mini. Why?" This depends on screen specs of device's. You will see another different brightness of your color in another smartphone.

Comment: @RKN: An ImageButton does not allow to set a text, font etc. And an "ordinary" Button does not allow you to add an image, which is my intention. I just commented it out to avoid any visual disturbances by the "transparent" background of my image.

Comment: @ChristianGraf Remvoe the color filters and check the original background of the ImageButton and Button: They should differ in brightness. This implies that the Backgrounds are originally different

Comment: They do differ. So how can I solve my prob?

Comment: is it possible for you to create the button in layout xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ChristianGraf Remove the color filters and check the original background of the ImageButton and Button: They should differ in brightness. This implies that the Backgrounds are originally different.

---

How can we solve this? We can not; simply, because the drawables used by system as backgrounds for ImageButton and Button differ in brightness. If you try the code on more devices you might notice more/other/less differences.

---

One solution could be to set the `PorterDuff.Mode` in the `setColorFilter` to SRC or DST. This will actually change the intended outcome.

---

***Solution*** (*Use one of the backgrounds twice*)

In your code, you first fix the backgrouond of `itemAddButton` (Button) using this line:

```
itemAddButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(BUTTON_BACKGROUND_COLOR_CODE,
PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Later on, you use the same code to set fix the background of `speechButton` (ImageButton):

```
speechButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(BUTTON_BACKGROUND_COLOR_CODE,
PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Now, all you have to do is instead of setting the color filter of the background, let us use the background of your first view (Button):

```
speechButton.setBackgroundDrawable(itemAddButton.getBackground());
```

This will ensure that they have identical backgrounds.